# Only return a decimal if it's not a whole number

Tags: java, if-statement, double, calculator

I've been trying to write a function `isWhole` that is given a double and looks to see if it's a whole number, and if it is return the value without the decimal (as an int?) else return it with 3 decimal places (I can do this part with number format.

My question is how can I check if a double is a whole number and even a recursive decimal?

Comment: What is the difference between a decimal number and its rounded down value?

Comment: The decimal point. How about splitting the double to an array, iterating through and checking if any of the any of the values are a"."

Comment: I don't know what a "recursive decimal" is, but if you mean a "repeating decimal", like 1/3 = 0.333333... or 1/27 = 0.037037037... -- you can't.  A `double` is incapable of representing numbers like 1/3 exactly.  Computers represent numbers in binary, and every number that a `double` represents exactly will be of the form N/(2^M) where N and M are integers.  And any such number, if it isn't a whole number, will have a decimal representation that terminates.

Comment: @ajb Of course, a "repeating decimal" is, IIRC, always representable as a ratio of whole numbers.  Unfortunately, however, once the number has been cast to float/double it's lost it's repeating character.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**[UPDATE]** returns value - with 3 decimal places

```
public boolean isWhole(double value) {
    return Math.floor(value) == value;
}
```

- You can't have a function that returns either `int` or `double`
- To convert `double` to `int`; simply **typecast** :- `int valueInt = (int) valueDouble;`

Comment: This is just equivalent to `return Math.floor(value) == value`.

Comment: Uuuhu. Your first solution was nice and clean apart from the unnecessary if. Now you mix formatting into the isWhole() test, whereby it does things the name does not advertise (violates clean code principles). Further it will break in all kinds of corner cases where conversion between binary and decimal representation is inexact.

Comment: @MiteshPathak: yes, well, but then we cannot return a double, because a double cannot be rounded properly to decimal places (except zero), due to the conversion issues between binary and decimal. We would then have to return a String after formatting.

Answer (score 2):

```
if(Math.abs(in-Math.floor(in)) < 0.001){
    /* is whole number */
} else {
    /* is not whole number */
}
```

Whole number isn't really defined for doubles, so a whole number can be seen as a number that has would not result in `n.000`. `0.001` is chosen specifically because it is the intended output precision.

Comment: I think the definition is quite clear. The OP wants to check for values that are mathematical integers. Casting to int will break for large double values like 1e300.

Comment: The corrected answer (using `floor` instead of `(int)`) is better. But the comparison should be to `0.0005` rather than `0.001`. REASON: Values that *round* to a whole number (when keeping 3 decimal digits) should be considered whole. If the value *rounds* to a non-whole, it should not be considered whole. For example, the input `1.00099` would round to `1.001`, and that is how it should be displayed.

Comment: Minor point: `Math.abs` is not needed.  See `floor` in http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html. Floor is always less-than-or-equal-to the input value. Final corrected answer: `if (in - Math.floor(in) < 0.0005)`

Comment: Alternative interpretation of OP, is to look for whole number within some smaller tolerance. So maybe `1.00000035` should display as `1`, but `1.0004` should display as `1.000` (where the zeroes seem unnecessary, but they are a clue that "significant" rounding occurred). To achieve this, perhaps do `(in - Math.floor(in) < 0.00001)`, though the value to use is rather arbitrary.

Comment: BTW, the answer doesn't say how to get the `whole value` out. In the whole number branch, do `Math.round(in)`. The result is a double, containing an integer value. That is, it has no decimal digits. For a string representation with no digits, do `String.format("%.0f", in)`. Ex: `String.format("%.0f", new Double(5.0/6))` results in `1`, because this format rounds.

Answer (score 2):

My first advice would be: keep it simple. Java has functions that make this sort of thing easy:

```
import java.Math;
public class MyFunctionsLibrary {
    public static boolean isWhole(double x) {
        if(x - Math.floor(x) == 0)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
    public static void testIt() {
        double a = 123.456;
        Integer whole = null;
        Double nonWhole = null;
        if(isWhole(a))
            whole = new Integer(Math.floor(a));
        else
            nonWhole = new Double(a);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This was my original answer:

How about

```
Math.floor(x)==x
```

The floor leaves the x unchanged, bit-by-bit if it is a mathematical integer (say the docs), so the equality should hold exactly when there is nothing to round.

After some thought, I think using exact comparison may lead to unwanted results. The question is, what the requirements of the OP really are. Is it

1. If it is a mathematical integer, show the number with no digits
   after the decimal point, if it is not, show 3 digits after the
   decimal point. Or is it
2. If formatting with three digits results in 000 after the decimal point, show only an integer.

The solution shown above and in other answers only works, if (1) is the requirement, because the number 2.000001 would turn out as 2.000, because it is not a mathematical integer.

If the Locale is fixed to a default, formatting 1.0 for the endsWith()-pattern can of course be optimized into a fixed string like ".000" or ",000".

If (2) is actually requested, my hunch is that there is no way around first formatting the number to a string and only then stripping the zeros, like so:

```
String format(Locale l, double d) {
  String zeros = String.format(l, "%.3f", 1.0d);
  String s = String.format(l, "%.3f", d); 
  if (s.endsWith(zeros.substring(1))) {
    return s.substring(0, s.length()-4);
  }
  return s;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

To see if a double is a whole number use

```
    double d;        
    int whole = (int) d;
    if(whole == d){
        return whole;
    }
    else{
        (your formatting here)
        return formattedDouble;
    }
```

You could check if it is recursive by creating:

```
  String s = d + "";
  for(int i = 1; i < s.length(); i++){
      if(s.charAt(i) == s.charAt(i-1)){
          continue;
      }
      else{
         return false;
      }
  }
```

Comment: (1) the first part - casting to `int` breaks for large doubles, that can't be represented in an int. It also has a slight code smell, because it relies on `(int)` doing truncation rather than round. Better to use @user60561's revised answer. That is, use `Math.floor` instead.

Comment: (2). Incorrect test of a repeating decimal. First, user must understand that a double does not exactly represent a `rational value`, so any representation of that decimal will not be exactly a repeating decimal. Second, a repeating decimal may have non-repeating digits to the left of the repeating portion. E.g. `1/6` becomes `0.1666..`. Because a double cannot exactly represent a repeating decimal, you have to make an *arbitrary* decision as to how many identical digits at the end mean "it repeats" ...

Comment: ... Third, the string representation will round, so `1/6` becomes `0.1666667`. So allow the last digit to be 1 larger, if the repeated digit is 5 or greater. But don't *require* it to be one larger - due to inexactness of double representation, you might happen to get `0.1666666` instead. Not for 1/6, but in a few cases. Fourth, that is an ugly way to convert to a string. Also, you probably want to specify how many significant places. Unless you know you have a small number, you'll have to use exponential (scientifica notation), and skip the exponent part. Code left to the reader. ...

Comment: ... it gets worse. Consider `(new Double(123456788.0/6)).toString()` => `2.0576131333333332E7`. Skipping exponent `E7`, we see that the final digit is `2` not `3`. Again, the inexactness of double. But if you say "I'll just skip the last digit and check what comes before", then what happens if you see `2.05761333335`. Is that a repeating decimal? No. On the other hand, it might *originally* have been a repeating decimal, but then you did some (non-exact) math, like adding another number to it, and it got *slightly off*. That's non-exact math for you.